# QR code, can be generated with R?

Tags: r, barcode, qr-code

Can QR codes be generated in R? Is there is a package that allows it?

Comment: You can now: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/qrencoder

Answer (score 16):

**Now on CRAN**

You can use the `qrencoder` package - https://github.com/hrbrmstr/qrencoder - to do this. It begs the question: *"Why?"*, though

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(qrencode_raster("http://rud.is/b"), 
      asp=1, col=c("white", "black"), axes=FALSE, 
      xlab="", ylab="")
```

[image]

Comment: *Why?* - I heard the digital currencies are the first practical usage of QR codes. See [accept payments in shiny app](http://www.r-bloggers.com/accept-payments-in-shiny-app/)

Answer (score 11):

There's also a CRAN package called `qrcode` now. 
check this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qrcode/index.html

usage is a as simple as it gets:

```
library(qrcode)
qrcode_gen('www.r-project.org')
```